# ordenar arreglo por monto descendentemente php

Tags: php, array

Necesito ordenar los valores de la columna amount en forma descendente, el arreglo es multidimensional.  No sirve order by ya que el arreglo se obtiene de múltiples consultas. Es un arreglo anidado por lo que es más complejo de ordenar, la estructura del arreglo(esquemático) es:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(22) {
      ["description"]=>
      string(26) "Egreso prube drag and drop"
      ["amount"]=>
      string(6) "3000"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(21) {
      ["description"]=>
      string(20) "Entidad editada 01-2"
      ["amount"]=>
      string(6) "43000"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(19) {
      ["description"]=>
      string(37) "Deuda en cuotas prueba (cuota 1 de 3)"
      ["amount"]=>
      string(6) "3000"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(19) {
      ["description"]=>
      string(37) "Deuda en cuotas prueba (cuota 2 de 3)"
      ["amount"]=>
      string(15) "5000"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(19) {
      ["description"]=>
      string(37) "Deuda en cuotas prueba (cuota 3 de 3)"
      ["amount"]=>
      string(15) "990"
    }
  }
}
```

imagino que usando un usort se puedo, pero no logro llegar a la manera correcta.

Comment: el arreglo se obtiene de consultas a varias tablas y se van agregando al arreglo mediante un push, por lo que tengo que ordenar el arreglo.

Comment: Hola, me parece que tratas de ordenar un array de arrays por el valor de un elemento anidado a un nivel n de profundidad ¿estoy en lo cierto?

Comment: @quevedo así es viene de una consulta a la base de datos.

Comment: Hay una manera **bonita** de hacerlo: 1. escribe una función `list($amount, $viejaclave) = claveParaOrdenacion($siguiente_item);` que te devuelva una pareja de valores y con ella haces un array de paso `$salida[$amount]=$viejaclave` que se ordena mediante sort y luego ese array reemplaza en $viejaclave el item correspondiente de tu array de arrays y lo pasas a la salida

Comment: No armas el array de salida de una vez para no enviar algo muy pesado al sort

Comment: @quevedo, podrías elaborarla más? como para dejarla como respuesta a la pregunta.

Comment: ¿ La estructura que muestras está tal cual la entrega la consulta ? o es esquemática? me hace falta para elaborar una respuesta

Comment: La tendrías en hora y media porque paso a almorzar

Comment: @quevedo de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: con json_decode(json_encode($result),true) evito que salgan los objetos en el arreglo, lo dejo como tip, actualicé el arreglo de la pregunta.

Comment: Para poder reproducir tu problema y ayudarte mejor, ¿podrías compartir el resultado de exportar esa información en JSON o usando `var_export()`? Edita tu pregunta y pon allí la información actualizada. Gracias.

Comment: Por otro lado, Si un elemento tiene subelementos, ¿a la hora de comparar se usa la suma de sus elementos o no se tienen en cuenta para nada? ¿Se trata cada elemento por separado? **¿Podrías explicar cómo quedarían ordenados los datos que has puesto de ejemplo?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien el planteamiento se trata de ordenar un array de arrays con varios niveles de profundidad por el valor situado bajo una clave que eventualmente es única en el árbol en que se encuentra, dónde se entiende por árbol a cada array situado en el primer nivel. Esquemáticamente hablando:

```
<?php
    $consulta = [
        $arbol_0, $arbol_1, ..., $arbol_n
    ];
// con $arbol_i = array( array, array, etc)  de modo que a algún subnivel
// se encuentra el par clave valor: 'amount' => valor que se quiere usar
// como criterio de ordenación
```

La solución debe enfocarse de la siguiente manera:

1. Construir un array de paso en el que las claves sean literales (para obtener un orden lexicográfico) determinadas a partir de los valores situados bajo la clave de ordenación deseada.
2. Ejecutar una función de ordenación como sort() o ksort() sobre el array temporal.
3. Pasar los árboles a un array de salida usando como guía el array temporal ordenado.

**Dificultad observable** Es posible que no se sepa a ciencia cierta cual es la posición en la que se debe leer la clave 'amount' para obtener el valor criterio de ordenación.
Para salvar esta dificultad, es necesario implementar un método de lectura recursiva que busque y devuelva todos los valores situados bajo una cierta clave, de modo que se sepa dónde están así:

```
<?php
    function leerRecursivamenteEnArray($clavealeer, $array){
        // ejecuta la lectura recursiva y devuelve un array de la forma
        $salida = ['path_1/hasta/clavealeer' => valor_1, 
                   // ... ,
                   'path_n/hasta/clavealeer' => valor_n];
        return $salida;
    }
```

De modo que recorriendo los paths usados como claves sea trivial encontrar los subarrays en los que se encuentra el valor.

**Ahora la implementación de la solución:**

1. Usaré una clase abstracta para hacer la lectura recursiva

```
<?php
abstract class Arrays2l {
    /**
     * Establece si la clave $key es usada en el array $array
     */    
    public static function arrayKeyCheck($key, $array)
    {
        return (isset($array[$key]) || array_key_exists($key, $array));
    }
    /**
     * Establece recursivamente si la clave $needle es usada en algún nivel de
       profundidad del array $haystack
     */
    public static function recursive_hasKey($needle, $haystack){
        if(self::arrayKeyCheck($needle, $haystack)){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            foreach ($haystack as $value) {
                if(is_array($value)){
                    if(self::recursive_hasKey($needle, $value)){
                        return TRUE;
                    }
                }
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Busca recoge y devuelve todos los valores situados a cualquier nivel de
     * profundidad bajo la clave $needle en el array $haystack, es privado porque
     * se desea evitar que el usuario tenga que declarar el &$getter
     */
    protected static function find_and_collect_values_under_key($needle, $haystack, &$getter, $path = ''){
        if(!is_array($haystack)){ return NULL; }
        if(!isset($getter)){ $getter = []; }
        $basepath = ($path) ? $path . '/' : '';
        foreach($haystack as $key => $value){
            if( is_array($value) && self::recursive_hasKey($needle, $value)){
                self::find_and_collect_values_under_key($needle, $value, $getter, $basepath.$key);
            }
        }
        if(self::arrayKeyCheck($needle, $haystack)){
            $getter[$basepath.$needle] = $haystack[$needle];
        }
    }
    /**
     * Busca lee y devuelve todos los valores asociados con la clave $needle
     * en el array multinivel $haystack a cualquier nivel de profundidad
     */
    public static function recursive_collectValues($needle, $haystack){
        $getter = [];
        self::_find_and_collect_values_under_key($needle, $haystack, $getter);
        return $getter;
    }
}//END class
```

2. **Método para crear las claves para ordenación lexicográfica**

```
<?php
function claveParaOrdenacion($valor){
   /**
    * Prefijo de ceros para forzar posicionalmente los valores numéricos
    * de modo que el orden de magnitud no destroce el orden.
    */
    $pad = '000000000000'; //con doce dígitos es suficiente (supongo)
    if(is_numeric($valor)){
       $entero = (int) $valor;
       $residuo = $valor - $entero;
       $temp = substr($pad.$entero, -12).$residuo;
    }else{
       $residuo = '';
       $temp = $valor;
    }
    return $temp;
}
```

3. **Creación y ordenación del array temporal**
   Como en el caso de tu problema se debe hacer la búsqueda recursiva dentro de los árboles de modo que suponemos que recibes la consulta a la base de datos en un array multinivel al que llamaré consulta y los nodos de primer nivel contienen los registros a ordenar.
   En consecuencia se hace un recorrido foreach para armar la estructura temporal:

```
<?php
// La consulta a ordenar se recibe en un array multinivel $consulta y
// se prepara un array temporal para ordenar la estructura
$salida = [];
$i = 0; // contador de iteraciones para desambiguar eventuales valores iguales
foreach($consulta as $clave => $registro){
    $busqueda = Arrays2l::recursive_collectValues('amount', $registro);
    // como se supone que en cada registro sólo aparece una vez la clave amount
    // puedo tomar el primer valor mediante array_shift
    $valor = (array_count($busqueda)>0) ? array_shift($busqueda) : '0';
    $i++;
    $salida[claveParaOrdenacion($valor).$i] = $clave;
}
// Ahora ordena por claves
ksort($salida);
```

4. Finalmente se reasignan los elementos de la consulta usando sus claves que se encuentran momentáneamente en los valores del array temporal ordenado

```
<?php
foreach ($salida as $clave => $viejaclave){
   $salida[$clave] = $consulta[$viejaclave];
}
// Ahora en $salida se encuentra la consulta ordenada por el valor situado en amount
```

Answer (score 0):

La entrada es:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array(), 
    array(
        array('description'=>"Descripcion 1", 'amount'=>"3000")
    ),
    array(
        array('description'=>"Entidad editada 01-2", 'amount'=>"43000")
    ),
    array(
        array('description'=>"Deuda ... (cuota 1 de 3)", 'amount'=>"3000"),
        array('description'=>"Deuda ... (cuota 2 de 3)", 'amount'=>"5000"),
        array('description'=>"Deuda ... (cuota 3 de 3)", 'amount'=>"990")
    )
);
```

Siguiendo la referencia oficial de PHP de [array_multisort()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-multisort.php),

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($data as $row) {
    $amount = array_column($row, 'amount');
    array_multisort($amount, SORT_DESC, $row);
    $new_array[] = $row;
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

Lo cual da como salida:

```
array(
    array(), 
    array(
        array('description'=>"Descripcion 1", 'amount'=>"3000")
    ),
    array(
        array('description'=>"Entidad editada 01-2", 'amount'=>"43000")
    ),
    array(
        array('description'=>"Deuda ... (cuota 2 de 3)", 'amount'=>"5000"),
        array('description'=>"Deuda ... (cuota 1 de 3)", 'amount'=>"3000"),
        array('description'=>"Deuda ... (cuota 3 de 3)", 'amount'=>"990")
    )
);
```

¿Te sirve esto?