# Cómo obtener el camino de todos los nodos de una jerarquía

Tags: javascript

Tengo una jerarquía de nodos en un checkbox tree y me gustaría saber cómo hacer una función recursiva que de cada elemento final de un nodo devuelva su camino completo, dependiendo de si esta seleccionado o no.

Lo máximo que he conseguido es que me devuelva todos los elementos finales.

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?

Gracias

Por ejemplo:

```
A
 -A1
  -A1.1
  -A1.2
   -A1.2.1
   -A1.2.2
   -A1.2.3
 -A2
 -A3
 -A4
```

Si todos están seleccionados, debería devolver lo siguiente:

```
0: A/A1/A1.1
1: A/A1/A1.2/A1.2.1
2: A/A1/A1.2/A1.2.2
3: A/A1/A1.2/A1.2.3
4: A/A2
5: A/A3
6: A/A4
```

Si el elemento no está seleccionado A1.2.2, debería devolver lo siguiente:

```
0: A/A1/A1.1
1: A/A1/A1.2/A1.2.1
2: A/A1/A1.2
3: A/A1/A1.2/A1.2.3
4: A/A2
5: A/A3
6: A/A4
```

Aquí está mi código:

```
export const getHierarchyNodes = (hierarchy: any) => {
    let idNodes: Array<string> = [];
    const clonedHierarchy = { ...hierarchy };
    // const parentId: number = clonedHierarchy.id;
    // const parentChildren: any = [];

    clonedHierarchy.children.forEach((child: any) => {
        if (child.selected || child.checked) {
            // const childNode: string = `${parentId}`;
            const descendetsNodes = getDescendetsNodes(child);
            console.log("descendents: ", descendetsNodes);
        }
    });

    return idNodes;
};

const getDescendetsNodes = (node: any) => {
    let descendents: string = "";

    const dmaExtractor = (children: any) => {
        children.forEach((child: any) => {
            if (child.selected || child.checked) {
                descendents += "/" + child.id;
            }

            if (Array.isArray(child.children)) {
                dmaExtractor(child.children);
            }
        });
    };

    if (Array.isArray(node.children)) {
        dmaExtractor(node.children);
    }

    return descendents;
};
```

Comment: Hola. Transforma tu problema en devolver los paths a elementos de un array multinivel haciendo búsqueda recursiva. En una respuesta [tag:php] que dí hace pocos días uso una clase que hace esa búsqueda. Te bastaría con transcribirla a [tag:javascript] y usarla iterando soble los elementos seleccionados. Si te interesa mira: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/423433/91033

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda pero si te soy sincero php lo tengo olvidadisimo y no pillo na xD

Comment: Otra solución: usa el selector de atributos `input[checked]` y acto seguido recorres sus parents hasta encontrar una raíz adecuada, que sabes cual es. Debes combinarlo con `input[type="checkbox"]`